# Webpack configuration for deployment [nodejs + babel + webpack]

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

I am using webpack to run react server-side application. For development I use babel-node but I have to create deployment package, I create such command for that:

`ENV=staging webpack -d --config webpack.config.dist.babel.js --display-error-details`

It is creating package in /dist folder. I am running node on this file:

`node dist/index.js` and this is working correctly, but when I copy /dist folder to another directory then after running same command I got such error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'babel/register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object.module.exports.obj.__esModule.default (/Users/xxxx/dist/index.js:64:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/xxxx/dist/index.js:21:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/dist/index.js:53:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/xxxx/dist/index.js:21:30)
    at /Users/xxxx/dist/index.js:41:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxx/dist/index.js:44:10)
```

I can't find solution for that, I was trying upgrade from babel 5 to 6 but it was very hard task and takes too much time. Have you got idea what can cause this problem ? I can add webpack configuration If you want.

Comment: Are you copying package.json to the dist folder? Try copying that and npm install on that folder.

Comment: @DiegoFernandez It is working, but I think it should include node_modules in final deploy files? I am not sure If it is good practice to use node_modules on production ?

Comment: Ideally `npm install` should run on production environment as part of the deploy script.